# How to use the prefix key in tmux and Vim?

Tags: vimrc, tmux

I am new to tmux.

I have some configuration added to my tmux configuration file.

I use <kbd>Ctrl Space</kbd> as prefix in tmux, and I want to use the same prefix key in Vim.

But I find that Vim uses <kbd>Ctrl Space</kbd> in split windows, it will treat as use prefix in tmux.

What should I do to allow use the same prefix key both Vim and tmux?

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) Could you precise what you mean by prefix key in Vim. Do you mean `<leader>` key?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear stateement, I mean the prefix key <kbd>ctrl w</kbd>, the key need to pressed beforeo jump between split window.

Comment: You may or may not be able to use `<C-Space>` as `g:mapleader`; if you want to send that key to an application, you generally have to set up a tmux binding to `send-prefix` (like my `bind-key -N 'prefix' C-Space send-prefix` which comes after `set -g prefix C-Space` and `unbind-key C-b`); then you have to press your prefix twice to send it once to the underlying application.